# Box - how to tell if the root folder has been modified?

Tags: box-api

I noticed that the call to https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0.xml does not return a modified-at tag.  How can I tell when the root folder has been modified?

A solution I came up with is to check the folders directly beneath the root folder for modified-at dates.  However, that could result in a significant amount of HTTP calls.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the V2 API returns nulls for the root folder's dates (created_at, modified_at).  We are looking at whether we can easily populate those fields on the root folder for you, instead of having you drill through the folders yourself.